AWS Greengrass is not downloading S3 Artifact to custom location
I have created a AWS Greengrass component to pull docker-compose file and a python script to run docker-compose. I am defining my artifacts as below, but the problem is my python script is getting downloaded correctly in component's root location but the docker-compose.yml file is not getting downloaded in custom location.
Due to which python script gives error and component is marked as broken and deployment simply fails.
{
    "RecipeFormatVersion": "2020-01-25",
    "ComponentName": "Backend_Services",
    "ComponentVersion": "2.3.3",
    "ComponentType": "aws.greengrass.generic",
    "ComponentDescription": "A component that updates BE, FE, DB and BACnet container from ECR and S3 compose file",
    "ComponentPublisher": "Amazon",
    "ComponentDependencies": {
        "aws.greengrass.TokenExchangeService": {
            "VersionRequirement": ">=2.0.0 <2.1.0",
            "DependencyType": "HARD"
        }
    },
    "Manifests": [
        {
            "Lifecycle": {
                "run": "python3 {artifacts:path}/auth-helper.py {artifacts:path}/containers"
            },
            "Artifacts": [
                {
                    "Uri": "s3://beartifacts/components/backend_services/docker-compose.yml",
                    "Digest": "dZ9DMTqHpULnDN8xIBHspspVFEUq/1EjmHcoVfPFXlI=",
                    "Algorithm": "SHA-256",
                    "Unarchive": "NONE",
                    "Permission": {
                        "Read": "OWNER",
                        "Execute": "NONE"
                    },
                    "Path": "containers/docker-compose.yml"
                },
                {
                    "Uri": "s3://beartifacts/components/backend_services/auth-helper.py",
                    "Digest": "vwkCkcBeORXfxSwiah9yjKan2GlkajzOuhSZTCaRbHQ=",
                    "Algorithm": "SHA-256",
                    "Unarchive": "NONE",
                    "Permission": {
                        "Read": "OWNER",
                        "Execute": "NONE"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Lifecycle": {}
}

The important point to note is that if I remove Path field from docker-compose artifact it also gets downloaded and containers are running after execution of python script. But directory structure is crucial for me to maintain, and I am not able to achieve the goal.
Any hint/suggestion is appreciated in advance.

Path is a not a valid attribute in Artifacts. See documentation here.
Remove Path, then the file will be downloaded in the same location as your auth-helper.py file.
If you require to have the folder structure in place, I suggest you zip everything with the proper folder structure. If you zip don't forget the "Unarchive": "ZIP" key value pair :)

Need to maintain directory structure as well, i need to download the compose file in containers directory and not in the current location as of auth-helper.py file .

why don't you zip everything with the proper folder structure? The Path key is not supported.

yes @brushtakopo its the solution i think can you please post this as an answer for me to accept and mark as solution

@ZainUlAbidin, done.
